# Converting string from C++ to Swift

Tags: c++, swift, objective-c, nsstring, objective-c++

I am trying to use C++ functions in Swift. To do that, I use an Objective-C wrapper. I am not familiar with Objective-C and C++ so much.

My *wrapper* function takes Swift String as a parameter from textField. And inside of C++ I encrypt the passed string and return it.

Here is my C++ function:

```
string StringModifier::encryptString(string str) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; (i<100 && str[i] != '\n'); i++) {
        str[i] = str[i] + 2;
    }
    return str;
}
```

And inside of the wrapper:

```
StringModifier stringModifier;

-(NSString*)encryptString:(NSString*)str; {
    string strng = [str UTF8String];
    string finalString = stringModifier.encryptString(strng);
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithCString: finalString.c_str() encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
    return result;
}
```

The output of encryptString("Helloworld") is "Jgnnqyqtnf¬√√0*?"
and after a couple of times calling this method, it throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you try `i<100 && str[i] != '\n' && str[i] != '\0'` in the for-loop condition?

Comment: This actually solved my problem. Never thought that was a problem on Cpp side. Thank you so much.

Comment: Added an answer for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for the null character (`\0`) in C++.

Change your for-loop to this:

```
for(i=0; (i<100 && str[i] != '\n' && str[i] != '\0'); i++) {
    str[i] = str[i] + 2;
}
```

Even better, loop depending on how big the string is:

```
string StringModifier::encryptString(string str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size() && str[i] != '\n'; i++) {
        str[i] = str[i] + 2;
    }
    return str;
}
```